# Continuous migration of DNS server

Tags: dns-zone

Good morning,

We are currently using CloudFlare to host our DNS zone. Yet, we'd like to move to Amazon Route53. And we'd like to make the switch progressively. We already have some apps in production, using some CloudFlare features such as SSL or custom page rules. Hence, we'd like to check if everything is right on under-used subdomains before making the big switch. :)

Here is the process I imagine:

- Add both CloudFlare and Route53 DNS servers to my registrar domain configuration,
- Add these same servers on both CloudFlare and Route53 zones NS record,
- Move some subdomains from CloudFlare to Route53.

Yet, I'm not sure about the last step.

Let's imagine we migrate `myapp.acme.com` from CloudFlare to Route53. So, the `A myapp` record won't be present on CloudFlare anymore. How does the resolution exactly work? Depending of the website I read, I understand it differently.

My guess is that resolution would try a server listed in NS record. If it finds `myapp` record, then it would return the resolved address. Otherwise, it will try another `NS` server from the list and apply the same process. Am I correct?

On the other side, other online resources insist on the synchronization of every zones. Is it mandatory for such a continuous migration?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You don't intend to stop using CloudFlare as a front end to your web servers? You should get CloudFlare to help you with this migration. Or just don't do it at all.

Comment: We plan to stop using CloudFlare soon (we already use CloudFront on AWS). We start using CloudFlare only as a DNS for our new apps. Hence this provider move. :)

Comment: In that case it's just like any other DNS migration. Copy your resource records, make sure you didn't make any typos, and then update your domain registration.

Comment: So, there is no possibility to do it incrementally? We need to migrate everything at once?

Comment: It's just one zone, right? The whole thing goes at once, then.

Comment: Yes, a single zone. Allright then! Thanks for your help! :)